# Some href links are not responding

Tags: css, hyperlink, menu, href

I am making a menu, but I have a problem with a link.

```css
body,html{
            margin:0;
            font:1em "open sans",sans-serif;
        }

        /**************/
        /*  MENU BAR  */
        /**************/


        .nav-main{
            width:100%;
            background-color:#222;
            height:70px;
            color:#fff;
            padding-left: 33%;
            padding-right: 33%;
        }

        .nav-main > ul{
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
            float:left;
            list-style-type:none;
        }
        .nav-main > ul > li{
            float:left;
        }
        .nav-item{
            display:inline-block;
            padding:15px 20px;
            height:40px;
            line-height:40px;
            color:#fff;
            text-decoration:none;
        }
        .nav-item:hover {
            background-color:#444;
        }
        .nav-content{
            position:absolute;
            top:70px;
            overflow:hidden;
            background-color:#222;
            max-height:0;
        }
        .nav-content a{
            color:#fff;
            text-decoration:none;
        }
        .nav-content a:hover{
            text-decoration:underline;
        }
        .nav-sub{
            padding:20px;
        }
        .nav-sub ul{
            padding:0;
            margin:0;
            list-style-type:none;
        }
        .nav-sub ul li a{
            display:inline-block;
            padding:5px 0;
        }
        .nav-item:focus{
            background-color:#444;
        }
        .nav-item:focus ~ .nav-content{
            max-height:400px;
            -webkit-transition:max-height 400ms ease-in;
            -moz-transition:max-height 400ms ease-in;
            transition:max-height 400ms ease-in;

        }
```

```html
<nav class="nav-main">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="http://www.google.com" class="nav-item">Search</a>
        </li>

        <li>
            <a href="#" class="nav-item">Extra's</a>
            <div class="nav-content">
                <div class="nav-sub">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="http://www.google.com">Instructions</a> </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

*try the links using [ctrl + click] to test the links*

The "Search" box **is working**, but if you click on "Extras" --> "Instructions", nothing is happening.

I think that the link in **Extra's** is preventing it to work.
But without the "**Extras**" as a link, the menu wont expand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this rule, so that the element is clickable:

```
.nav-item:focus ~ .nav-content,
.nav-content:hover {
    max-height:400px;
    -webkit-transition:max-height 400ms ease-in;
    -moz-transition:max-height 400ms ease-in;
    transition:max-height 400ms ease-in;
}
```

It is because, you have assigned the event on the `focus`, it goes off when you try to click on the link.

```css
body,html{
            margin:0;
            font:1em "open sans",sans-serif;
        }

        /**************/
        /*  MENU BAR  */
        /**************/


        .nav-main{
            width:100%;
            background-color:#222;
            height:70px;
            color:#fff;
            padding-left: 33%;
            padding-right: 33%;
        }

        .nav-main > ul{
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
            float:left;
            list-style-type:none;
        }
        .nav-main > ul > li{
            float:left;
        }
        .nav-item{
            display:inline-block;
            padding:15px 20px;
            height:40px;
            line-height:40px;
            color:#fff;
            text-decoration:none;
        }
        .nav-item:hover {
            background-color:#444;
        }
        .nav-content{
            position:absolute;
            top:70px;
            overflow:hidden;
            background-color:#222;
            max-height:0;
        }
        .nav-content a{
            color:#fff;
            text-decoration:none;
        }
        .nav-content a:hover{
            text-decoration:underline;
        }
        .nav-sub{
            padding:20px;
        }
        .nav-sub ul{
            padding:0;
            margin:0;
            list-style-type:none;
        }
        .nav-sub ul li a{
            display:inline-block;
            padding:5px 0;
        }
        .nav-item:focus{
            background-color:#444;
        }
        .nav-item:focus ~ .nav-content, .nav-content:hover {
            max-height:400px;
            -webkit-transition:max-height 400ms ease-in;
            -moz-transition:max-height 400ms ease-in;
            transition:max-height 400ms ease-in;

        }
```

```html
<nav class="nav-main">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="http://www.google.com" class="nav-item">Search</a>
        </li>

        <li>
            <a href="#" class="nav-item">Extra's</a>
            <div class="nav-content">
                <div class="nav-sub">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="http://www.google.com">Instructions</a> </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

add to your css

```
.nav-content:hover{
  max-height:400px;
}
```

because max-height of nav-content only have 400px when focus .nav-item, if you click in other site .nav-content lost max-height and you didn´t click in link